# Test for presence of substring in a collection of strings

Tags: php, substring

I want to test whether a substring is in a string using php.

For example,

```
$str="Cycle";
$str1="Cycle,Yoga";
```

I want to check `if (str in str1)`.

Comment: use strpos or strstr function

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of **`stripos`**

```
if (stripos($str1,$str) !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) (for case-sensitive String) or [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)(for case-insensitive) for string matching.

```
if (strpos($str1,$str) !== false) {
    // It'll check the case-sensitivity of string
    echo 'true';
}

if (stripos($str1,$str) !== false) {
    // It'll ignore the case-sensitivity
    echo 'true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use strpos or stripos

```
$mystring = 'Cycle,Yoga';
$findme   = 'Cycle';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
if ($pos !== false) {
    echo "true";
}
```